# How to properly store an image to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, android-studio

I have already stored some data in the SQL Server database with this code

```
_bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
_bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
bytesImage = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
image = Base64.encodeToString(bytesImage, Base64.DEFAULT);

String query =
    "INSERT INTO EloanApp(SeqID,AppImage) VALUES ('" + seqid + "','" + image + "')";
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

And to make it sure that if it is successfully uploaded the image, I tried to export the image stored in my database and opened it, the photo viewer, shows **"It looks like we don't support this file format."** what seems could be the problem here?

PS.

I exported the image with this method

[Simple Image Import and Export Using T-SQL for SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4963/simple-image-import-and-export-using-tsql-for-sql-server/)

Comment: It seems very strange that you are storing you image as a string in the database... why not store as `varbinary` and use a parameter to pass the data to the database.

Comment: @DaleK it is stored as binary data

Comment: No, you are base64 encoding it, then storing it as a string. At least according to your code.

Comment: @DaleK dude thanks for the tip. I've solved my problem. Ughh so silly.

Comment: I removed the answer from your question, as you have correctly posted it as a solution - which you can self-accept after some time period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that removing this line

```
image = Base64.encodeToString(bytesImage, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and using a `PreparedStatement` to execute my query

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO EloanApp(SeqID,AppImage) VALUES(?,?);

preparedStatement.setString(1, seq_id);
preparedStatement.setBytes(2, bytesImage);
preparedStatement.execute();
```

solved the issue!